# Solving a linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assuming that p not equals to $0$, state conditions under which the linear differential equation

$$y'+p(x)y=f(x)$$

is separable. If the equation satisfies these conditions, solve it by separation of variables and by one other method.

What i tried

Im confused about this question, because I think this is a linear equation and could be solve by the integrating factor method and i dont see how the seperable method can be used. What it attempted was to move the RHS of the equation to the LHS to give   $y'+p(x)y-f(x)=0$. I then divide the LHS of the equation by $f(x)$ , my guess is that this equation is seperable only when $f(x)=p(x)$. However im stuck from here onwards. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: I would go further and add that any function $p(x) = nf(x)$ where $n$ is any number.

Comment: What happens if $f(x) = 0$?

Comment: The equation becomes $$y'+p(x)y=0$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A separable first-order linear differential equation is of the form
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=a(x)b(y)$$
Our differential equation being
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=f(x)$$
we want to reduce it to the first form above, and thus we're looking for the appropriate functions $a(x)$ and $b(y)$. Therefore we can write
\begin{align}a(x)b(y)&=f(x)-p(x)y\\&=p(x)\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{p(x)}-y\right)\end{align}
And we set $a(x)=p(x)$. Now, $\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}$ must be independent of $x$, so we set $f(x)=kp(x)$, with $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, our reduced equation is
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=p(x)\cdot(k-y)$$
which is indeed separable as
$$\int\dfrac{dy}{k-y}=\int p(x)dx$$
Also note that in the case $k=0$, we get the first-order linear homogeneous equation
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=0$$

Answer (score 0):

It appears the condition is $f(x)=kp(x)$ for some constant $k$.  In this case

$$y'=kp(x)-yp(x)=p(x)(k-y)$$

Can you handle it from here?

Comment: Yup i got it, is it necessary to add the constant $K$, because i equate $f(x)=p(x)$ without a constant.

Comment: @yswong That would be the case for $k=1$.  Mattos's hint was trying to show you that $f(x)=0$ $(k=0)$ also produces a separable equation.  Including the $k$ seems to be a better answer, but I'm not $100\%$ positive there aren't any other cases.

Comment: @Mike There aren't.